# Does Key length in NameValueCollection affect the search performance?

Tags: .net

I only concern with Search performance. Adding or Deleting entry in the NameValueCollection is not important here.

Does Key length in NameValueCollection affect the search performance as in GetValues(Key)? Will I get the values in NameValueCollection significant faster if using significant shorter Key length?

Comment: You are basically asking if string.Equals is faster with shorter strings. Of course it is, if there is a full book to compare it takes longer than if there is a single letter to compare. But why does it matter? Measure it for your specific strings and see if it makes a difference. Performance should not be the key factor but if your key is unique or readable (or whatever is important for you).

Comment: I am not sure. I heard previously they use Hash in Key.

Comment: Yes, there is a `Hashtable` and `GetHashCode` uses the hash, but afterwards the strings must be compared with `Equals`. So the lookup might be efficient but you still need to compare at least two strings with `Equals`. As i said, that should not matter much unlike you dont store a book as key.

Comment: I am facing with options. Option1, use content as Key, Option2 uses UniqueId as Key but needs additional step to retrieve the Content. I am evaluating the cost of doing implementing these.

Comment: If the content is the key, what is the value?

Comment: Other data associated with the Content